# filtering stopwords near punctuation

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to filter out stopwords in my text like so:

```
clean = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in (stopwords)])
```

The problem is that `text.split()` has elements like `'word.'` that don't match to the stopword `'word'`.

I later use `clean` in `sent_tokenize(clean)`, however, so I don't want to get rid of the punctuation altogether.

How do I filter out stopwords while *retaining punctuation*, but filtering words like `'word.'`?

I thought it would be possible to change the punctuation:

```
text = text.replace('.',' . ')
```

and then

```
clean = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in (stop words)] or word == ".")
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokenize the text *first*, than clean it from stopwords. A tokenizer usually recognizes punctuation.

```py
import nltk

text = 'Son, if you really want something in this life,\
        you have to work for it. Now quiet! They are about\
        to announce the lottery numbers.'

stopwords = ['in', 'to', 'for', 'the']

sents = []

for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    sents.append(' '.join([w for w in tokens if w not in stopwords]))

print sents
```

['Son , if you really want something this life , you have work it .', 'Now quiet !', 'They are about announce lottery numbers .']

Comment: `nltk.word_tokenize(text)` would have avoided the namespaces.

Comment: `word_tokenize` not `tokenizer`;P

Comment: clean loses all punctuation in the process though? For example, `sent_tokenize(clean)` no longer has any delimiters to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
import re

clean = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if re.match('([a-z]|[A-Z])+', word).group().lower() not in (stopwords)])
```

This pulls out everything except lowercase and uppercase ascii letters and matches it to words in your `stopcase` set or list. Also, it assumes that all of your words in stopwords are lowercase, which is why I converted the word to all lowercase. Take that out if I made to great of an assumption

Also, I'm not proficient in regex, sorry if there's a cleaner or robust way of doing this.